# Best way to iterate in sequence with some async operations

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I want to iterate **in order** through multiple arrays while apply some async operations.

Is there another way to get an Array iterator that will work in Node? Is there a way I can get rid of the callbacks?

```
    let viewModel = {
    pages: [
        {
            id: 'pageOne',
            states: [
                {
                    id: 'stateOne'
                },
                {
                    id: 'stateTwo'
                },
                {
                    id: 'stateThree'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 'pageTwo',
            states: [
                {
                    id: 'stateOne'
                },
                {
                    id: 'stateTwo'
                },
                {
                    id: 'stateThree'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

function* arrayIterator(_array){
    while(_array.length > 0) yield _array.shift();
}

function loadBrowser(){
    return pseudoAsync('loaded browser');
}

function stateActions(state){
    return pseudoAsync('actioning: ' + state.id);
}

function processState(state, states, callback) {
    if(!state.done) {
        console.log(state.value.id);
        stateActions(state.value).then(()=>{
            processState(states.next(), states, callback);
        });
    } else {
        callback();
    }
}

function processPage(page, pages) {
    if(!page.done){
        console.log(page.value.id);
        loadBrowser().then(()=>{
            let states = arrayIterator(page.value.states);
            processState(states.next(), states, ()=>{
                processPage(pages.next(), pages);
            });
        });
    }
}

let pages = arrayIterator(viewModel.pages);
processPage(pages.next(), pages);


function pseudoAsync(message){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{

        setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log(message);
            resolve();
        }, 2000)

    });

}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/J5dwLJRuMwez4HpF1HGq)

This is the expected output order:

- pageOne
- loaded browser
- stateOne
- actioning: stateOne
- stateTwo
- actioning: stateTwo
- stateThree
- actioning: stateThree
- pageTwo
- loaded browser
- stateOne
- actioning: stateOne
- stateTwo
- actioning: stateTwo
- stateThree
- actioning: stateThree

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Since you already tagged your question `async`/`await`, why not just use it?

```
for (const page of viewModel.pages) {
    console.log(page.id);
    await loadBrowser();
    for (const state of page.states) {
        console.log(state.id);
        await stateActions(state);
    }
}
```

> Is there another way to get an Array iterator that will work in Node?

Sure: [`arr[Symbol.iterator]()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@iterator) or `arr.values()`. It's implicitly used by `for … of`.

> Is there a way I can get rid of the callbacks?

Use promises properly, and don't try to manually advance the iterator.

Comment: Await\Promise would allow my other pages\states to begin processing. I want to prevent the next page or state from starting before the last one has completed.

Does Array.values work in Node? I haven't looked at the Symbol.iterator syntax, thanks.

Comment: @moefinley No, they would `await` the completion before continuing with the next, that's the whole point?

Comment: They will stop the execution within the current function. Not all my async operations are in the same function.

Comment: @moefinley Just have every async operation return a promise (as you always should). Then you can call and await them individually. Each operation might itself be written as an `async function` that again awaits its subprocessing steps.